# Android Service stops working when app closes in Titanium

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, android-service, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I have created a service that runs when i close my app by pressing back button. I dont know whether it is right Approach or not but it works fine when the App is running in foreground.
I have my `androidService` file is placed in android folder and its entry is there in tiapp.xml file.

in my `androidService.js` file

```
  var locUpdate = require('/locationUpdate');
  locUpdate.userLocationUpdate();
```

Now I have a doubt that whether we can use the module or call a module in a service. Or I have to write my all logic(The API call etc) in the Service file only. [Using SDK 2.0.1] any help

Comment: did you have any luck with this?